# Can UEFI firmware force the OS to change its boot mode?

Tags: windows, uefi

Windows 8 and 10 are by default booting with Hiberboot enabled, so when you go to Start->Power->Shutdown, the system actually goes into S4, not S5. I need to be able in some circumstances to force Windows to perform a full boot instead of "wake" from S4, regardless of how it was previously shut down. I tried to force my UEFI BIOS BootMode to always be BOOT_WITH_FULL_CONFIGURATION, but it does not help - Windows still takes the fast boot path.

In the past, it was possible to set the DIAG mode with Simple Boot Flag in the BIOS; that might work for me, but it does not seem like it is still supported in Windows 8/10. Is there some UEFI variable or some other means of communicating to the OS to boot in either full or diagnostic mode?

Comment: solution for your problem would be highly tied to implementation and hardware you using i.e. new Intel chipstes have stick registers which preserve boot state until CMOS battery reset. Can you provide more information about hardware you use ?

Comment: Why would the solution be tied to hardware? I need my UEFI driver to tell the OS in a more or less standard way that although it chose to shutdown via hibernation, on this boot it needs to discard the hiberfil data and perform a full boot or diagnostic boot. I use an Atom-based platform for experiments, but this must work with any hardware. Can you please elaborate what boot state info is preserved in the sticky registers, which the OS is supposed to examine to make the boot type decision?

Comment: This is pretty complex topic. First thing is that firmware always know from which ACPI state you are booting and based on that decide what boot path to choose. The way how firmware obtain that information is hardware and firmware dependent. Implementation of your application will not be trivial. You want to cheat ACPI states and OS about previous hardware state. Please check [this](http://superuser.com/a/1012982/64511) post. Also please provide exact Atom model so I can look into datasheet and point you to registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve this problem. I register an ExitBootServices event callback, and in that routine I check if the boot mode is BOOT_ON_S4_RESUME. I also check my other internal conditions, so if the system wakes from S4 and I need to force a diagnostic/full boot, I just do gRT->ResetSystem (...). The ExitBootServices event is far enough into the Windows boot process, so a sudden reset at that point makes it scrap the Hiberfil data and do a full boot.

There seems to be no visible adverse effects, such as any error messages - it boots clean after the reset. Visually, the reset happens right after showing a Windows logo, so the user experience should also be okay. I do not know if this method will make it to production code, but I think it was a successful experiment.

Comment: interesting solution I wonder if this will not affect Windows stability long term, also wonder how Linux or other systems will behave. `ExitBootServices` is called by system bootloader that's why you see splash screen before reset. For sure OS didn't have chance to do anything about previous state. I'm most worried about hardware that is mainly out of BIOS control (ME, AMT, BMC), also wonder what various drivers in system will do if they figure out that woke up was from S5 not S4.